# Refreshing parent page after iFrame has submitted dta to MySql

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have read so much on this subject but still totally confused on how I should resolve my issue.

I have page1.php (parent) which contains an iFrame page2.php. On page2.php (the iframe) I have a form with a button and when clicked submits data to a MySql table. All this works fine.

What I am trying to do is; when the button on page2.php (the iFrame) is clicked, submit the data as it does now and then refresh page1.php (parent).

Can anyone push me in the right direction to make this happen.

Many thanks in advance.

Dereck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reloading the parent can be done for example by means of JavaScript that is executed in the answering page (in your case page2.php).

To give you a clue - assume we have page1 ...

```
<html>
<body>Container HTML ...
  <script>
    document.writeln(new Date());
  </script>
  <br>
  <iframe src="test2.htm"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

that loads the following page "test2.htm" ...

```
<html>
<body>
  IFrame ...
  <a onclick="doit(); return false;" href="#">reload parent ...</a>
<script>
  function doit() {
    parent.location.href = parent.location.href;
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When you click on the link in the IFrame the parent will be reloaded (including the iframe). This is done in the JavaScript function. (Just try it out).

In your case you could send just ...

```
<script>
    parent.location.href = parent.location.href;
</script>
```

Hope this clarifies the solution.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply, as you say, it works.